# Error on the multi-part identifier could not be found 

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, error-handling, sql-update

i've got some problem on update. and got "the multi-part identifier could not be found" because i use to update in another table in different database but the field use are same.
can you help me please.

here is the code:

```
UPDATE [interface].[dbo].[tre_bos_account_update]
SET [interface].[dbo].[tre_bos_account_update].n_tre_bos_account_update_start_balance = [SasTempDB]..OLT_Balance_Update.StartOfDayBalance
FROM (SELECT StartOfDayBalance from OLT_Balance_Update 
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(12), [sastempdb].dbo.OLT_Balance_Update.DateTrx) = CONVERT(varchar(12), GETDATE()))OLT_Balance_Update
WHERE [SasTempDB]..OLT_Balance_Update.ClientNo = [interface].dbo.tre_bos_account_update.vc_tre_bos_account_update_account_no
```

Answer (score 2):

`OLT_Balance_Update` is an alias for a derived table in your statement and is not part of a database.

Remove `[SasTempDB]..` from the places where you reference `OLT_Balance_Update` in your main query and probably add it to the from clause of your derived table. You also need to add ClientNo in your derived table.

Something like this:

```
UPDATE [interface].[dbo].[tre_bos_account_update]
SET [interface].[dbo].[tre_bos_account_update].n_tre_bos_account_update_start_balance = OLT_Balance_Update.StartOfDayBalance
FROM
  (
   Select StartOfDayBalance, ClientNo 
   from [SasTempDB]..OLT_Balance_Update -- This is the actual table in [SasTempDB]
   where CONVERT(varchar(12), [sastempdb].dbo.OLT_Balance_Update.DateTrx) = CONVERT(varchar(12), GETDATE())
  ) OLT_Balance_Update -- This is a table alias for a derived table
WHERE OLT_Balance_Update.ClientNo = [interface].dbo.tre_bos_account_update.vc_tre_bos_account_update_account_no
```

Looking at your query I would guess this is an equivalent.

```
update T
set n_tre_bos_account_update_start_balance = O.StartOfDayBalance
from interface.dbo.tre_bos_account_update as T
  inner join SasTempDB.dbo.OLT_Balance_Update as O
    on T.vc_tre_bos_account_update_account_no = O.ClientNo
where O.OLT_Balance_Update.DateTrx >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0) and
      O.OLT_Balance_Update.DateTrx < dateadd(day, 1+datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

The `dateadd`/`datediff` trick on `getdate()` will remove the time part from the date and comparing using `>=`/`=` will make SQL Server able to use a index on `OLT_Balance_Update.DateTrx` to find the rows it needs.